# Subfigure isn't working

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption, subfig

I'm trying to create a figure with two tikzfigures as subfigures. The problem seems to be in the `subcaption` style. This is the error that I'm getting:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \c@subfigure already defined.
> Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
%\usepackage{mutavel}   % Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master                    
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[russian]{babel}

\RequirePackage{subcaption} 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\asbuk{subfigure}}
  
%%%%%%%TIKZ%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}    
% FIGURES
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfigure[Image 1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,-5)  node[anchor= east]{x}; %X
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(5,0)  node[anchor=west]{z}; %Z
    
    \coordinate[label=$A$] (a) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$B$] (b) at (5,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$C$] (c) at (1,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$D$] (d) at (5,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$\textup{к.т}$] (control) at (3,-4);
    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](a)--(b)--(5,-5)--(1,-5)--(a);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](3,-1)--(3,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-4)--(5,-4);
    \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=1.8] coordinates{(3,-4)}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subfigure[Image 2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,-5)  node[anchor= east]{x}; %X
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(5,0)  node[anchor=west]{z}; %Z
    
    \coordinate[label=$A$] (a) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$B$] (b) at (5,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$C$] (c) at (1,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$D$] (d) at (5,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$\textup{к.т}$] (control) at (3,-4);
    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](a)--(b)--(5,-5)--(1,-5)--(a);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](2,-1)--(2,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](3,-1)--(3,-5);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](4,-1)--(4,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-2)--(5,-2);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-3)--(5,-3);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-4)--(5,-4);
    \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=1.8] coordinates{(3,-4)}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{MWE}
    \label{fig:ejemplo}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Works if the style is commented, and looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages `subcaption` and `subfigure` are not compatible. For example, they both define counter "subfigure".

To choose one from them, I recommend `subcaption`, which is under better maintenance. So, to make your example work,

- Remove the line `\usepacakge{subfigure}`
- Change two occurrences of `\subfigure` command to `\subfloat`.
- [Optional but recommended] Replace `\RequirePacakge` by `\usepackage`, the former is designed for use in document classes and packages.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
%\usepackage{mutavel}   % Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master                    
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\asbuk{subfigure}}
  
%%%%%%%TIKZ%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}    


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Image 1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,-5)  node[anchor= east]{x}; %X
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(5,0)  node[anchor=west]{z}; %Z
    
    \coordinate[label=$A$] (a) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$B$] (b) at (5,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$C$] (c) at (1,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$D$] (d) at (5,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$\textup{к.т}$] (control) at (3,-4);
    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](a)--(b)--(5,-5)--(1,-5)--(a);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](3,-1)--(3,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-4)--(5,-4);
    \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=1.8] coordinates{(3,-4)}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subfloat[Image 2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,-5)  node[anchor= east]{x}; %X
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(5,0)  node[anchor=west]{z}; %Z
    
    \coordinate[label=$A$] (a) at (1,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$B$] (b) at (5,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$C$] (c) at (1,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$D$] (d) at (5,-5.65);
    \coordinate[label=$\textup{к.т}$] (control) at (3,-4);
    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](a)--(b)--(5,-5)--(1,-5)--(a);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](2,-1)--(2,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](3,-1)--(3,-5);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](4,-1)--(4,-5);    
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-2)--(5,-2);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-3)--(5,-3);
    \draw [line width=0.25mm](1,-4)--(5,-4);
    \draw plot [mark=*, mark size=1.8] coordinates{(3,-4)}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{MWE}
    \label{fig:ejemplo}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Those packages are includes in `mutavel` style. Should I replace `\RequirePacakge` by `\usepackage` there?

Comment: @OscarEspinosa In general: in `cls` or `sty` file, use `\RequirePackage`. In `tex` file than contains `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`, use `\usepacakge`.